# Long Press Home button disable recent App

Tags: android, android-homebutton, long-press

I'm developing a Home Application for Android devices. I want to disable long press home button action of recent App. I googled and found some solution but didn't get the solution I want. Right now I'm using this piece of code. It worked, disable Home button recent app but It also closed any other app launch by user.

```
    @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (!hasFocus) {
        Toast.makeText(staticPosContext, "No Focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        am.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
    }

}
```

Comment: try android:excludeFromRecents="true" in activity of your manifest.

Comment: not working. I already tried it. But thanks.